# How to make a correct comparison between those results

Tags: matlab

Let's say I have to solve a linear system, `Ax = b`.
To obtain `x` I coded an algorithm within a function, `solve1`, then I want to check if the vector obtained is equal to the vector that the built-in Matlab function will give.

Example:

```
x = solve1(A, b);
x_matlab = A \ b;

if x ~= x_matlab
   error('My algorithm is not correct');
end
```

I know that the comparison I wrote is incorrect because if one component of one vector would change by a bit, it will fail.

What is the correct condition to make my idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:** If you are looking for the biggest deviation between matrices on an element-by-basis, why not use `max` -

```
diff1 = abs(x - x_matlab);
max_error = max(diff1(:))
```

Then, if you would like to be 100% strict about equality, use something like -

```
if max_error>0
    error('My algorithm is not correct');
end
```

Otherwise, use some tolerance value -

```
if max_error>TOL
    error('My algorithm is not correct');
end
```

**Method 2:** There is a MATLAB built-in function for strict comparison - [`isequal`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html)

**Method 3:** If you suspect more than one element to differ, you might look into `rms` -

```
rms_error = rms(x(:) - x_matlab(:))
```

You may use tolerance on RMS error values too.

**Note:** If you are working with decimal numbers, you might be needed to use some non-zero tolerance values that use [`eps`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/eps.html), so that precision issues are taken care of.